# position().left is null or not an object (IE only)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jquery-1.6

I want to popup an image if caps lock is active. It works fine on FF and Chrome. But as almost always not on IE (8). It states

> 'position().left' is null oder not an object

I also tried offset().left with the equivalent result

I made a bin here: http://jsbin.com/oyeyix/1 (please ignore the missing image)